# How to set slider initial value in swift?

Tags: swift, slider

How to set slider initial value by using code? I know how to do it in attribute inspector. I'd like to use "UserDefault" as the initial value when my app starts and when my app starts for the very first time, I'd like to set the initial value as "1.0"

```
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {
    sliderlabel.text = String(slider.value)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(slider.value, forKey:"playSpeed")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set slider value like so:

```
slider.setValue(1, animated: true)
```

and if you want to grab it from Userdefaults, you can:

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "playSpeed")
slider.setValue(value, animated: true)
```